# Updating two controls at the same time which bound to same bindingsource VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, listbox, bindingsource

I have a access database source bound to a Listbox in a parent form and i have one datagrid view in a child form both are bound to a same binding source. When i insert a new record or new line in the database through Datagridview in the child form it gets updated in the database as well as in datagrid view but the change was not reflected immediately in the Listbox i have to restart the program to see the changes in the listbox. Is there a way to push the change in both controls or update the listbox when i close the child form? I am using following code to update  my binding source.

```
With EQtblBindingSource
    .AddNew()
    DirectCast(.Current, DataRowView)("eiD") = "SS"
    DirectCast(.Current, DataRowView)("EQ_NAME") = "DUMMY"
    .EndEdit()
End With
EQ_tblTableAdapter.Update(EQDATADataSet.EQ_tbl)
```

thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that they are 2 different `EQtblBindingSource` I assume you plopped a dataset/table object in designer to auto generate all the objects such as the BindingSources to both forms in question? In this event the forms are not using the same bindingsource. You would need to pass the bindingsource from FormA to FormB as a param and wire up the controls manually.

Comment: yes you are right..every form has 1 binding source but with the same name..in this case how can do it?

Comment: why bindingsource.resetbindings() doesnt work

Comment: Its not the bindingsource that is the 'problem' what youre running into is that the datatable doesnt have the data, you need to refill the datatable on formA

Comment: I am not real sure it's a good idea to use the Mr. Wizard designer and try to modify his code. My experience with designing applications VIA designer is next to zero. I cant tell you if its a good idea to pass a reference to a bindingsource from class to class or not in this nature. You are probably better off refilling the datatable, presumably VIA the TableAdapter.Fill method

Comment: thanks..i solved it by calling tableadapter.fill in parentform